# Mongodb: How to drop a collection named "stats"?

Tags: mongodb

I created a collection named "stats" but whenever I try to delete it by using `db.stats.drop()` cmd line. It shows an error.

```
TypeError: db.stats.drop is not a function
```

Even tried this.

```
db["stats"].drop
```

Any solution?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/drop/

Comment: @p.streef still the similar error.

Comment: How are you executing these commands?

Comment: On cmd line. Windows. Monogdb.

Comment: dont do that, that will drop the whole DB not the collection

Comment: db.runCommand({drop : "stats"});

Comment: db.runCommand({drop : "stats"}) worked. Thank you. Why don't write an answer? There's no option to accept the comment.

Comment: I've added it as an answer so you can accept for future reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the collection exists db.stats.drop() should work (depending on the mongodb version maybe) or else perhaps db.getCollection("stats").drop();

but if all else fails, run: `db.runCommand({drop : "stats"})` this should drop it if it exists without any error at least.